# Can I use ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader / eager loading to load a has_one relationship with dynamic conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :latest_action, 
    :class_name=>'Action', 
    :conditions=> Proc.new {["action_at <= ?", self.timezone.now.to_date]},
    :order=>"action_at desc"
end

create_table "actions", :force => true do |t|
  t.date     "action_at"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I would like to do this:

```
users = User.limit(10)
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(users, [:profile => :latest_action]).run
```

or this:
    User.includes(:profile => :latest_action).limit(10).all

However, this fails:

```
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 2
Profile Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" IN (133622, 133623)
NoMethodError: undefined method `timezone' for #<Class:0x007fc5992152f8>
```

This works when I'm dealing with a single record:

```
User.last.profile.latest_action
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Profile Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = 242222 LIMIT 1
Action Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "actions".* FROM "actions" WHERE "actions"."profile_id" = 231220 AND (action_at <= '2013-08-27') ORDER BY action_at desc LIMIT 1
```

**Can I use a Proc to generate dynamic conditions on a has_one association and use that association in an ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader call or with eager loaded associations via include?**

It seems like in the in pre-loader / eager loading context, self in the conditions proc is a class not an instance.

I am on Rails 3.2.13

**Note**
I realize I could load the association like this, but I can't use that with the preloader

```
class Profile
  has_many :actions do
    def latest
      where("action_at <= ?", proxy_association.owner.timezone.now.to_date)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You could just create a `latest` scope and a `has_many :actions`, and use `User.first.profile.actions.latest` instead of `User.first.profile.latest_action`.

Comment: getting the latest action for a single User isn't the issue, its preloading the latest action for 20+ users.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `self` isn't your object in the `has_many`, it's the association proxy. If you want the `profile` object that is referenced in the association, it should be `owner` (though this is slightly dependent on the version of Rails you're running -- check the [documentation for Rails association extensions](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods) for more details).

Comment: I think that is true if I declared it to be has_many :actions do latest(date) { ... } but I can't preload the latest actions that way (I believe)  when you declare an association extension that way you can use proxy_association.owner or some other mechanisms to get back to the owning object.  In my case here, it looks like all I get in the block is the class (Action) and no instances.